# Change debug = true to false

Tags: templates, debugging, django-templates, syntax-error

`from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Product

def product_detail(request, slug):
print('Slug:', slug)
return render(request, 'store/product_detail.html', )

for views.py

`I'm having difficulty getting my template to work.

I'm creating an ecommerce store on vs code virtual environment, and after I created the url to the product, it tells me template does not exist.

I've tried everything in every tutorial I can find, but nothing is working.

I also tried debugging, but I got stuck along the way.

I need help to move forward.

[Template does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LV6S5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

#### Please Check those things...

```
1st - check your application is registered or not in settings.py
2nd - in the template folder store/product_detail.html exist or not make sure the template name should be same as you typed in views.py

if these two things are okay then the project should be worked
```

Comment: I checked. They're all correct, but error remains.

Comment: Plz add screenshot of your whole project directory

Comment: and also add settings.py & views.py code function which renders product_detail.html

Comment: views.py from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Product 

def product_detail(request, slug):
    print('Slug:', slug)
    return render(request, 'store/product_detail.html', )

Comment: I don't know how to properly add my code here.